# How to use a for loop without using different id tags for each input?

Tags: javascript

How to use a for loop without using different id tags for each input? The result for the javascript works however I want to know how to use for loop so I do not have to change every id tags in order to achieve the same result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Pathway+Gothic+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Book Ordering System</title>
    <style>

        body{
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#FF7F50,#008080);
        }
        thead,
        tfoot {
            background-color: skyblue;
        }

        tbody td:nth-child(5) input,
        tbody td:nth-child(6) input,
        tbody td:nth-child(7) input {
            text-align: right;

        }

        tr:hover {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        td:last-of-type input {
            background-color: silver;
        }

        tfoot,
        tfoot input {
            text-align: right;
        }

        tfoot td:last-of-type input {
            font-size: 18pt;
        }
        table{
            border-style: dashed;
            border-width: medium;
            border-color: #EEE8AA;
        }
        tbody td:nth-child(5) input,
        tbody td:nth-child(6) input{
            background-color: tomato;
        }
        tbody td:nth-child(2) input{
            background-color: #00FF7F;
        }
        tbody td:nth-child(3) input{
            background-color: #EE82EE;
        }
        tbody td > select{
            background-color: #FFA500;
        }
        table:active {
            background-color: green;
        }
        h1{
            font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
        }
        thead th{
            font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
            color: #CD5C5C;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <table border="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Book Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <input type="button"  onclick="calculateTotal();" value="Calculate Grand Total Price">
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="text" name="grandTotal" id="grandTotal" value="0.00" readonly="readonly">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec1" id="sec1" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec2" id="sec2" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec3" id="sec3" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec4" id="sec4" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec5" id="sec5" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec6" id="sec6" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec7" id="sec7" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec8" id="sec8" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec9" id="sec9" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec10" id="sec10" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec11" id="sec11" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec12" id="sec12" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec13" id="sec13" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec14" id="sec14" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec15" id="sec15" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec16" id="sec16" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec17" id="sec17" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec18" id="sec18" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec19" id="sec19" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec20" id="sec20" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec21" id="sec21" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec22" id="sec22" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec23" id="sec23" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec24" id="sec24" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec25" id="sec25" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        function calculateTotal(){

            let total = 0;

            let num1 = document.getElementById("sec3").value ;
            let num2 = document.getElementById("sec4").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec5").value = (num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
            total += (num1 * num2);

            num1 = document.getElementById("sec8").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec9").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec10").value = (num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
            total += (num1 * num2);

            num1 = document.getElementById("sec13").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec14").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec15").value = (num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
            total += (num1 * num2);

            num1 = document.getElementById("sec18").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec19").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec20").value = (num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
            total += (num1 * num2);

            num1 = document.getElementById("sec23").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec24").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec25").value = (num1 * num2).toFixed(2);
            total += (num1 * num2);

            document.getElementById("grandTotal").value = total.toFixed(2);
        }
        
       </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How to use a for loop without using different id tags for each input? The result for the javascript works however I want to know how to use for loop so I do not have to change every id tags in order to achieve the same result.

Comment: Writing the same question multiple times doesn't make it any better or more interesting.

Comment: Do you have an actual problem? Have you tried anything so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest, use class to get element instead of IDs.
Assign class to each column as below:

```
                       <td>
                            <label for="sec3"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="sec3" id="sec3" class="unit-price" value="0.00" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="sec4"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="sec4" id="sec4" class="units" value="0" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="sec5"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="sec5" id="sec5" value="0.00" class="total-units-price" readonly="readonly" />
                        </td>
```

Then try below JS code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            function calculateTotal() {

                let total = 0;

                $('tbody tr').each(function(){
                    let unit_price = $(this).find('.unit-price').val();
                    let units = $(this).find('.units').val();
                    let total_units_price = Number.parseFloat(unit_price) * units;
                    total_units_price = Number.parseFloat(total_units_price).toFixed(2);
                    $(this).find('.total-units-price').val(total_units_price);
                    total += total_units_price;

                })
                total = Number.parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById("grandTotal").value = total;
            }
            
        </script>
```

If you don't want to use Jquery at all here is pure javascript snippet for you:

```
<script>
    function calculateTotal() {
        let total = 0;
        let rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
            let unit_price = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('unit-price')[0].value;
            let units = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('units')[0].value;

            let total_units_price = Number.parseFloat(unit_price) * units;
            total_units_price = Number.parseFloat(total_units_price).toFixed(2);

            rows[i].getElementsByClassName('total-units-price')[0].value = total_units_price;
            
            total =  Number.parseFloat(total) + Number.parseFloat(total_units_price);
        }
        document.getElementById("grandTotal").value = total.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

Note: You have to putt this script in `<head>` section to resolve the error:
`test.html:101 Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateTotal is not defined`

Or bind function with click event like:

```
$('button').on('click', calculateTotal());
```

Hope you got it now and it works for you. Let me know if still facing any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to assign a class name for this kind of task, so replace the IDs with a class name so u can access them all at once

check this code

```
<body>
    <td>
        <label for="sec3"></label>
        <input type="text" name="sec3" class="sec3" value="0.00" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="sec4"></label>
        <input type="text" name="sec4" class="sec4" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="sec5"></label>
        <input type="text" name="sec5" class="sec5" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
    </td>

    <script>
        function calculateTotal(){
            let total = 0;
            let num1 = document.querySelectorAll(".sec3");
            let num2 = document.querySelectorAll(".sec4");
            let tot = document.querySelectorAll(".sec5");

            for(uPrice of num1){
                for(q of num2){
                    for(t of tot){
                        t.value = (uPrice.value * q.value).toFixed(2);
                        total += t.value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        calculateTotal();
    </script>
</body>
```